# JPEGMetadata cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, metadata, jpeg, exif

I am working on a program that is essentially going to be a **EXIF data stamper** for exclusively JPEG images.

The GUI is going to consist of a search box a load button and a display box to display the EXIF data. But i am running into an issue with the reader:

```
public class MetaRead {
    public String readCustomData(byte[] imageData, String key) throws IOException{
        ImageReader imageReader = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("JPEG").next();

        imageReader.setInput(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData)), true);

        // read metadata of first image
        IIOMetadata metadata = imageReader.getImageMetadata(0);

        //this cast helps getting the contents 

        JPEGMetadata JPEGmeta = (JPEGMetadata) metadata; 
        NodeList childNodes = JPEGmeta.getStandardTextNode().getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = childNodes.item(i);
            String keyword = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("keyword").getNodeValue();
            String value = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue();
            if(key.equals(keyword)){
                return value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am getting an error at `{JPEGMetadata JPEGmeta = (JPEGMetadata metadata;}` **"JPEGMetadata cannot be resolved to a type"**

the original code was for a PNG so i replaced all PNG with JPEG with find/replace.

Comment: Do you mean that the original code was, for example:


`PNGMetaData PNGmeta = (PNGMetadata) metadata;`?

Comment: yes it was originally that.

Comment: This is like saying "I needed to hire a German interpreter, so I found a French interpreter and replaced French with German in his resume, but why can't he understand German people?"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Okay, well. I don't know how to explain this without being blunt.

In programming, you can't just change the name of the object `PNGMetadata` to `JPEGMetadata` and expect it to work.

You see, the object `PNGMetadata` is developed to work for and ONLY for PNG images. You can't just change the name to JPEG and expect it to work for it.

If you need something to work for JPEGs, I can recommend a library to read JPEG metadata. See the link below.

https://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/

Comment: OK thank you, I know I seem like an idiot. I have never worked with metadata before and I'm still learning. I am Fairly new to Java programming and doing this as a project for my internship.

Comment: Well, I never called you an Idiot! ;)

You'll keep going and learning.

I can promise you that you won't make this mistake EVER again.

If you do, I'll find you and give you a good smack!

Good luck, friend!